# Why do some NiFi HTTP responses take so long?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've noticed that when I issue 200 responses via NiFi, the response is typically immediate.  However, 404 and 500 errors seem to take so long that they often cause the client to timeout.

Is this an intentional behavior?  Or is my `HandleHTTPResponse` processor possibly setup wrong?

--

Edit: While answered below, it's worth clarifying -- the `HandleHTTPResponse` was not behaving differently; I just happened to be routing [penalized] flowfiles to processors that were set to give 404/500 error codes ... so, it appeared there was a correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failed requests might be penalized. Check out the settings on your failure path and update the default 30 seconds value to 0, which makes more sense when handling expected http errors.

Comment: Setting the penalty to 0 for the processor **upstream** of the `HandleHTTPResponse` processor was the fix.  It seems that, despite immediately appearing in the downstream `Failure` queue, the presence of an upstream penalty will hold the flowfile.  I suspect NiFi's documentation notes this, but -- via its UI -- NiFi doesn't make this very clear.

Comment: In fact, https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#settings-tab covers this behavior ... "[Penalization] will prevent the FlowFile from being Processed for [the set] period of time."

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which responses are taking this long, my guess is that the error responses are being generated by an exception which may be thrown due to an internal timeout (i.e. waiting for some other connection or operation which fails to complete, exhausting the timeout, which leads to the HTTP response taking so long). You can profile these operations in the JVM if you like.

Comment: They immediately go to the failure connection but then just sit in the queue directly upstream the HandleHTTPResponse processor.